# How to confirm/verify WiFi is WPA2?

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, wpa-supplicant

How do I, from the command line, confirm *on the host* that the wireless network connection uses WPA2?

The wireless router is set to use `WPA2 Personal` (WPA2 with a pre-shared key) and AES on the network, and I have added `wpa-ssid`, `wpa-psk` and `wpa-proto RSN` to /etc/network/interfaces, but iwconfig prints `Encryption key:off`. I am running Debian Wheezy/7.0. I checked the system logs but saw nothing of relevance, and the only current [wpa_supplicant.conf](http://hostap.epitest.fi/gitweb/gitweb.cgi?p=hostap.git;a=blob_plain;f=wpa_supplicant/examples/wpa-psk-tkip.conf) on my system is one for D-Bus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check what the access point is broadcasting in its beacons by doing this (you'll need the `wireless-tools` package):

```
$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning
```

The output varies by device, and will display every SSID the interface can see.  My WPA2 access point gives this (from `iwlist`'s *very* verbose output):

```
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
    Group Cipher : TKIP
    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

You can also interrogate `wpa_supplicant` directly, which might be more what you're after:

```
$ sudo wpa_cli status
Selected interface 'wlan0'
bssid=c8:d7:19:01:02:03
ssid=whatever-SSID-you-are-using
id=0
mode=station
pairwise_cipher=CCMP
group_cipher=TKIP              <-- cipher
key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK              <-- key mode
wpa_state=COMPLETED
ip_address=10.20.30.4
address=88:53:2e:01:02:03
```

Comment: **Perfect!** wpa_cli says `pairwise_cipher=CCMP`, `group_cipher=CCMP` and `key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK`, and looking at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCMP), *"CCMP is the standard encryption protocol for use with the WPA2 standard and is much more secure than the WEP protocol and TKIP protocol of WPA."* `iwlist scanning` says only CCMP and PSK are available. That sounds good enough for me!